# ffmpeg av_bitstream_filter_init always return NULL

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am now using `ffmpeg` to do something interesting, using NDK,under android.
Now my problem is when I call av_bitstream_filter_init

```
AVBitStreamFilterContext *ctx = av_bitstream_filter_init("h264_mp4toannexb");
```

**ctx always NULL**

I have no ideas now,any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you're calling

```
    av_register_all();
```

**before** calling av_bitstream_filter_init

Comment: indeed It's my ffmepeg so's problem , tks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Make sure bsfs is not disabled when compiling ffmpeg:

```html
--disable-bsfs
```

REF: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html